# React components not re-rendered on state change

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks

**Issue number 1 - solved by adding `value` attributes to the input fields**

The first component should have the three input fields emptied upon submission.
The state changes properly but nothing happens on screen - title, author and url are properly emptied but the previous text value stays visible and the component does not re-render:

```
import React, { useState } from 'react'
import blogService from '../services/blogs'

const CreateBlog = props => {
  const [title, setTitle] = useState('')
  const [author, setAuthor] = useState('')
  const [url, setUrl] = useState('')

  async function handleCreate(event) {
    event.preventDefault()
    try {
      const blog = { title, author, url }
      await blogService.create(blog, props.token)
      props.changeblogAdded()
      setTitle('')
      setAuthor('')
      setUrl('')
    } catch(error) { console.log(error) }

  }

  return (
    <form id="new-blog-form" onSubmit={handleCreate}>
      <h2>Create new blog</h2>
      {`title `}<input type="text" required onChange={event => setTitle(event.target.value)}></input>
      <br></br>
      {`author `}<input type="text" required onChange={event => setAuthor(event.target.value)}></input>
      <br></br>
      {`url `}<input type="url" required onChange={event => setUrl(event.target.value)}></input>
      <br></br>
      <button type="submit">create</button>
    </form>
  )
}

export default CreateBlog
```

**Issue number 2**

The `props.changeblogAdded()` call in the child component is supposed to change the state of the parent App component, and it does so successfully but the parent component does not re-render either:

```
import React, { useState } from 'react';
import Blogs from './components/Blogs'
import Login from './components/Login';
import CreateBlog from './components/CreateBlog'

function App() {
  const [token, setToken] = useState('')
  const [blogAdded, setBlogAdded] = useState(false)

  function changeblogAdded() {
    setBlogAdded(!blogAdded)
  }

  function displayBlogs() {
    return (token ? <Blogs></Blogs> : '')
  }

  function newBlogForm() {
    return (token ? <CreateBlog token={token} changeblogAdded={changeblogAdded}></CreateBlog> : '')
  }
  console.log(blogAdded);
  return (
    <div className="App">
      <Login setToken={setToken}></Login>
      {displayBlogs()}
      {newBlogForm()}
    </div>
  );
}

export default App;
```

How can I set the CreateBlog and App components to properly re-render?

Comment: Issue 1: I think the problem is that your `<input>` elements are not controlled. You need to pass values in inputs... e.g. `<input value={title} onChange={...} .../>`

Comment: @euvs that's right, funny I missed it.
Still have no idea regarding the second issue though.

Comment: The code seems good. It must be whatever is going on in the `CreateBlog` component. The component will only re-render if the state actually changes, so this method must not be getting called in the child component for whatever reason.

Comment: If you need to change the state in reference to the previous value, you need to pass a function that takes the previous state as an argument to the state-setting function, e.g. `setBlogAdded(wasBlogAdded => !wasBlogAdded)`

Comment: Why cant this method be called in the child component? it does seem to change the `blogAdded` value from the child when I use it, but the `App` component still doesn't re-render.
I've tried `setBlogAdded(wasBlogAdded => !wasBlogAdded)`, but I changed it to this function since I don't really care about the previous state, its just a toggle (of sort) function.